# Python websockets recv

Tags: python, websocket

Не очень понимаю как решить данную проблему

```
    async def connect_to_simpledevice(admin_websocket: WebSocketServerProtocol,
                              controller_websocket: 
 WebSocketServerProtocol):
    """
    CONNECTING, OPEN, CLOSING, CLOSED
    """

    print(f'\nSimpleDevice connection'
          f'\nAdmin websocket state: {admin_websocket.state}'
          f'\nController websocket state{controller_websocket.state}')

    async for message in admin_websocket:
        print(message)
        await controller_websocket.send(message)
        response_controller = await controller_websocket.recv()
        
        Здесь ошибка RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another 
        coroutine is already waiting for the next message
       
        print(f'Response from controller: {response_controller}')
        await admin_websocket.send(message)
```

Ошибка - RuntimeError: cannot call recv while another coroutine is already waiting for the next message

Я так понимаю, что ему не нравится 2 recv(). Как это исправить?

Comment: можете вставить минимально воспроизводимый код?

Comment: @AndrewHolovko добавил

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657602/waiting-to-recv-on-two-websockets решение пока не нашёл